# Traefik V2 (armv6) - Reverse Proxy with SSL termination - without Docker

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have a raspberry pi that I want to use for SSL termination and as a reverse proxy for other pis running services.

Why?  I was able to get HTTPS using my Synology NAS but ACME recently got upgraded in Let's Encrypt and my NAS version is too old.  I also want to use Traefik as a learning experience.

I have managed to successfully install Traefik V2 -outside of Docker- and it is running fine and redirecting to the appropriate back-end servers.  However, SSL doesn't work.  Not sure what I might have configured incorrectly.  I appreciate anyone's help.

I see the following error on the web interface, but I can't find any log files being created in the specified path.

[image]

After burning my eyes reading their docs and anything I could find online, I have the following 'traefik.yaml' file:

```
#################################
# Traefik V2 Static Configuration
#################################

# Global Configurations
global:
  # Check for Update
  checkNewVersion: true

# Configure the transport between Traefik and your servers
serversTransport:
  # Skip the check of server certificates
  insecureSkipVerify: true
  # How manny connections per server
  maxIdleConnsPerHost: 42
  # Define timeouts
  forwardingTimeouts:
    dialTimeout: 42
    responseHeaderTimeout: 42
    idleConnTimeout: 42

# Configure the network entrypoints into Traefik V2. Which port will receive packets and if TCP/UDP
entryPoints:

  # HTTP Entry Point
  web:
    # Listen on TCP port 80  (80/tcp)
    address: ":80"
    # redirect http to https
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          # Where to redirect
          to: web-secure
          # Scheme to use
          scheme: https
          # Make it always happen
          permanent: true
    # Specify the timeouts for the transports
    transport:
      # Controls the behavior during the shutdown phase
      lifeCycle:
        requestAcceptGraceTimeout: 42
        graceTimeOut: 42
      # Timeouts for incoming requests to Traefik V2 instance. No effect on UDP.
      respondingTimeouts:
        readTimeout: 42
        writeTimeout: 42
        idleTimeout: 42
    # Define how the Proxy Protocol should behave and what to trust.
    proxyProtocol:
      # Specify IPs for secure mode
      trustedIPs:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 127.0.0.1
    forwardedHeaders:
      # Specify IPs for secure mode
      trustedIPs:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 127.0.0.1
  
  # HTTPS Entry Point
  web-secure:
    # Listen on TCP port 80  (80/tcp)
    address: ":443"
    # Define TLS with Let's Encrypt for all
    http:
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt
    # Specify the timeouts for the transports
    transport:
      # Controls the behavior during the shutdown phase
      lifeCycle:
        requestAcceptGraceTimeout: 42
        graceTimeOut: 42
      # Timeouts for incoming requests to Traefik V2 instance. No effect on UDP.
      respondingTimeouts:
        readTimeout: 42
        writeTimeout: 42
        idleTimeout: 42
    # Define how the Proxy Protocol should behave and what to trust.
    proxyProtocol:
      # Specify IPs for secure mode
      trustedIPs:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 127.0.0.1
    forwardedHeaders:
      # Specify IPs for secure mode
      trustedIPs:
      - 10.0.0.1
      - 127.0.0.1

# Configure the providers
providers:
  providersThrottleDuration: 42
  
  # If using a dynamic file
  file:
    filename: "/etc/traefik/traefik-dynamic.yaml"
    watch: true
    debugLogGeneratedTemplate: true
    
  rest:
    insecure: true

# Traefik's Dashboard located in http://<ip>/dashboard/ (last / necessary)
api:
  # Enable the dashboard
  dashboard: true

# Location of Log files
log:
  # Logging levels are: DEBUG, PANIC, FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO
  level: DEBUG
  filePath: "/etc/traefik/traefik.log"

# SSL Certificates
certificatesResolvers:
# Use Let's Encrypt for SSL Certificates
  letsencrypt:
    # Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt automatic SSL)
    acme:
      # E-mail used for registration
      email: <my e-mail>
      # Leave commented for PROD servers uncomment for Non Prod
      #caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      # File or key used for certificates storage.
      storage: acme.json
      # Optional 
      #keyType: RSA4096
      
      # Use HTTP-01 ACME challenge
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web
```

And the following 'traefik-dynamic.yaml' file:

```
#################################
# Traefik V2 Dynamic Configuration
#################################

# Definition on how to handle HTTP requests
http:

  # Define the routers
  routers:

    # Map Traefik Dashboard requests to the Service
    Traefik:
      middlewares:
      - BasicAuth
      rule: "Host(`traefik.subdomain.dns1.us`)"
      service: api@internal
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

    # Map PLEX to the Server
    # No EntryPoints defined so that it listens in all of them
    PLEX:
      rule: "Host(`plex.subdomain.dns1.us`)"
      service: PLEX
      tls:
        certResolver: letsencrypt

  # Define the middlewares
  middlewares:
    # Basic auth for the dashboard
    BasicAuth:
      basicAuth:
        # Specify user and password (generator: https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator)
        users:
          - "<user>:<password>"

  # Define the services
  services:

    #PLEX Service
    PLEX:
      loadBalancer:
        # Backend URLs
        servers:
        - url: "http://10.0.0.21:32400"
        # Enable sticky sessions
        sticky:
          cookie: {}
        # Pass the client Host header to the server
        passHostHeader: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the /etc/traefik/acme.json file.

I removed it and restarted the Raspberry Pi.  Traefik re-created the file and no errors showed up.